# How to answer single-node-edit Queries on DAG for Longest Weight Path

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

Formally , we r given a graph G with 'n' nodes each having a +ve numbers on it. we are given directed edges with no cycle. then we are asked to answer Q queries , each query asks to edit a node's weight on G and we have to print Weight of Longest Weight path. Note, each query means editing one single node from Original graph .
N<=10^5 & Q<=10^6 . What is the most time-effecient solution?

Ofcourse bruteforce will take O(n*q) which is too much. i tried 2,3 variation of bruteforce which gives much better avg time complexity but i can find atleast one test-data for each solution that if we ask repeatedly  is as bad as O(n*q).

Comment: Please tidy up the formatting and use complete words ('are' instead of 'r') - your question currenly isn't understandble.

Comment: @Jost :Okay, Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer queries in O(1) time each, it suffices to know, for each node, the weight of the heaviest paths that do/don't use that node, because the weights of paths within these classes are affected additively by changing the node's weight. The "do use" half is accomplished straightforwardly in O(n) time by, e.g., computing for each node the weight of the heaviest paths for which that node is a source/sink.

The "don't use" half is what makes this question interesting. Assume that the nodes are numbered 1..n in topological order with arcs directed from lower to higher. Using the computed data from before, we can, given an arc u->v, compute in O(1) time the weight of the heaviest path that includes that arc. Such a path definitely skips nodes u+1..v-1, so we can update the "don't use" maximums for those nodes accordingly. If we do this for all arcs, including some sentinel arcs from a sentinel source 0 with weight 0 to 1..n to a sentinel sink n+1 with weight 0, then we get the correct "don't use" values.

Now, doing this in the obvious fashion is way too slow: O(m n) time for preprocessing for a total time of O(m n + q), where m is the number of arcs, n is the number of nodes, and q is the number of queries. A segment tree reduces the preprocessing time to O(m log n).